# Close all socket into an arraylist

Tags: java

Hello I'm learning scocket and I have a small problem. I can create a socket and close them one by one. Then I put in an Arrylist. For the moment no problem, everything works correctly. But now I'd like to close a socket and all the others will close as well (possibly with a 10 seconds delay but that's secondary).

```
if(sc.isClosed()){
    System.out.println("Deconnexion all socket");
    for(int i = 0; i<tabsc.size();i++)
        tabsc(i).close();
    break;
}
```

Something like this (it doesn't work of course)

if you have an idea I'm interested. Thanks

Comment: "*...it doesn't work of course...*" - Why not?

Comment: Include more code.  The code you currently have is not java and may not compile.